# How to support landscape orientation for only single scene in Storyboard IOS 6.0 & 7.0?

Tags: ios6, ios7, storyboard, xcode5, uiinterfaceorientation

Hi am using storyboard to design UI my entire application.It  will support Portrait mode for all screen  except reports screen.In Reports i have to show huge data so it should be in landscape mode.And  also using tabbar controler.

My Question is 1. :is there any possible to support different orientation in storyboard?

**P.S:** i have tried to rotate view to landscape mode its working fine but am unable to hide tab bar and status bar in my application for particular screen.

2.It possible to handle orientation programatically for all scene?(to support portrait/landscape)

**P.S:** I have changed my plist to support landscape left/right.But it roating to landscape for all screen.i tried below code for my landscape but its not woking .

```
-(BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    return YES;
}

-(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations{
    return  UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape;
}

- (UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape;
}
```

Please guide me.thanks in avance

Comment: @MC yes somewhat I handled but really not known is proper solution

Comment: The only way to solve this is to set the project to portrait and rotate that view only.

Comment: Yes am just rotating view and setting up view.Thanks for reply @Mc-